# How to replicate the "~/"-to-home & "//"-to-root behaviour in ido-find-file but for a custom directory?

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

When calling `ido-find-file` it's possible to type `~/` to replace the current working directory with your home directory automatically:

```
Find file: /etc/{...} # after typing ~/ becomes:
Find file: ~/{...}
```

How can I replicate this but for a custom directory such as `user-emacs-directory` and when pressing a key instead of inserting text in the minibuffer? For example:

```
Find file: /var/log/{...} # after pressing F6 becomes:
Find file: ~/.emacs.d/{...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just about to make a blog post about this (I'll do it later anyway):

```
(defun oleh-ido-setup-hook ()
  (define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map "~"
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (ido-set-current-directory "~/")
      (setq ido-exit 'refresh)
      (exit-minibuffer))))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'oleh-ido-setup-hook)
```

Comment: Added the post: http://oremacs.com/2015/01/09/ido-find-file-tilde/

Comment: Excellent. Very precise and informative post. Thanks!